# Android Application with app engine backend support using PHP sdk

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine

I want to know can I connect an android app which includes PHP scripts calling a mysql database.
I have my database on the Google Cloud SQL while the PHP scripts are running on the cloud courtsey the PHP whitelisting of my app.

Can I acheive this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2uhwve5kspkcya/android_backend.png

Comment: Yes, why not. Do you have any actual question/problems with performing your described plan?

Comment: Hi Patrick.Thanks for replying. I have completed most of the process. 1.I have uploaded the database on the Cloud SQL console. 2.Configured the Android App to call my PHP scripts. 3.And also, configured my PHP scripts to connect with the Cloud SQL database. I was having some issues understanding App engine. I need you to help me out here. The PHP app is hosted on the app engine but what about the android app.Does it not need app enigine support too or just deploying the PHP app is enough. Hope I am clear enough.

Comment: @Abhishek Have you got any solutions for this.If so Please provide some suggestions.